# How can I open image file with fopen function in FTP Server in php

Tags: php

```
$conn = ftp_connect("ftp.mywebsite.com") or die("Could not connect");
ftp_login($conn,"admin","password");
$self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$file = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
if ($_FILES['file']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) 
{ 
   die("Upload failed"); 
}
else
{ 
   $fp = fopen($file, 'r')or die("Unable to open $file for reading");

  if(ftp_fput($conn, $file,$fp, FTP_BINARY))
  {
     echo "success";  
  } 
  else 
  {  
     echo "error"; 
  } 
}
```

How can I open image file with fopen function in FTP Server in php. (failed to open stream: No such file or directory )

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason in using fopen function on FTP Server.

Assuming from your code, your real task is just to safe uploaded file on the same server. 
you have to use `move_uploaded_file()` then

If you really need to save uploaded file not locally but on FTP server, ftp_put $_FILE['file']['tmp_name'] then.

Comment: in local server, I can run by (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $file)) but FTP server I use ftp_fput($conn, $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] ,$fp, FTP_BINARY)
Error Warning: ftp_fput() [function.ftp-fput]: The parameter is incorrect.

Comment: @linlin i'd suggest you to experiment with local file first, and make it uploaded on FTP. only then move to save uploaded file. It's hard as hell to catch an error while doing 2 tasks at once.

Comment: @Col Thanks for reply me. Now, I use move ()
$uploaddir = 'uploads/'; 
$file = $uploaddir.basename($_FILES['file']['name']); 
if ($_FILES['file']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) 
{ die("Upload failed"); }
else
{if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $file))
{ echo "success"; } 
else { echo "error"; } 
}

Comment: when I use ftp_fput(), I got error (The parameter is incorrect.) what do I need to give? am I missing something
ftp_fput($conn, $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] ,$fp, FTP_BINARY)

Comment: @linlin you are apparently missing manual page. http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php tells you what parameters you have to use. Also, I told you already, you have to divide your task into 2 parts. Do not do 2 things at once. send LOCAL FILE, not uploaded one. And set appropriate parameters for the ftp_put manually, using NO VARIABLES

Comment: I have poor logic. Now, I change the way. first, I check file type and If ok, I save in the table, then I display it. Its display immidieatly. I am not sure that this is the best way. I don't know how to keep photo dynamically in FTP server. I am developing for one of the group as volunteer. Thanks Col and everybody.